# Ejecutar comando php desde ajax

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo una cuenta atrás (countdown) hecho con jquery, desde una función ajax recibo una fecha y se "crea la cuenta atrás" hasta llegar a esa fecha.

Mi duda es que como puedo ejecutar un comand php desde la función OnFinish (es decir cuándo acabe el contador).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/cuentaatras",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        // var res = data['fechaEmpieza'];
        var res ="2020-06-03 22:08:00";
        var fecha= new Date(res)


$(function(){    
    $('#countdown').countdown({
        timezone:+4, //zona horaria

        //establecemos la fecha exacta en qué termina el countdown
        year: fecha.getFullYear(),
        month: fecha.getMonth()+1,
        day: fecha.getDate(),
        hour: fecha.getHours()+2, //formato 24hr
        minute: fecha.getMinutes(),
        second: fecha.getSeconds(),

        //Establecemos qué haremos luego que termina el countdown
        onFinish: function () {
                // var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
                alert("holaa");


        } 
    });

});
    }


});
```

Editado:

La comanda que quiero ejecutar es "php artisan revisionbingo" , para que funcione esta comanda tiene que ejecutarse desde la ruta "C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoBINGO>", se tendria que ejecutar varias veces, yo tengo un script el cual me funciona pero supongo que llamar a un script desde ajax no se puede o requerira de librerias.

Comment: le haces un nuevo `$.ajax` dentro del `onFinish` al php que quieras ejecutar, habría que validar el timer para que no sea invocado antes de tiempo por consola ( un hmac generado en el primer ajax tal vez? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos por su tiempo, me ayudaron a aclarar dudas, finalmente buscando encontré la siguiente comanda que me funcionó.

```
Artisan::call("revisionbingo");
```

Lo ejecuto desde una función php, dentro del OnFinish hago un for y llamo a esta función las veces que necesito.

```
onFinish: function () {
            for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/pruebacmd",
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data) {

                    }
                });
                setInterval(3000);
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando Laravel te recomiendo usar la clase `Process` de symfony la cual es muy útil para ejecutar comandos y saber si el comando ha funcionado, se utiliza de la siguiente manera.

Estas son las clases que debes incluir:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
```

Con este comando ejecutas el proceso:

```
$process = new Process("php artisan revisionbingo");
$process->run();
```

Compruebas si el comando se ejecuto correctamente

```
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
```

Con este comando optienes la salida del proceso

```
echo $process->getOutput();
```

Comment: He editado la pregunta aclarando unas cosas, en la parte de abajo. Yo no necesito llamar a una función php, lo que necesito es ejecutar automaticamente cuándo acabe el countdown la comanda "php artisan revisionbingo" en la ruta "C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoBINGO>"

Comment: Vale ya actualice mi respuesta, supongo que estas utilizando laravel

Comment: Sii, he probado con el Process, supongo que lo estoy usando mal debido a que me salta la condición del if, he tenido que poner la comanda entre corchetes si no no funcionaba , The command ""php artisan revisionbingo"" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoBINGO\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ ""php artisan revisionbingo"" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
 programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el comando no se esta ejecutando en el lugar correcto, pues se esta ejecutando en C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoBINGO\public y es por eso que no puede acceder a artisan. lo que podrías hacer es cambiar el comando que ejecutas por `(php C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoBINGO\artisan revisionbingo)` o `(cd C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoBINGO && php artisan revisionbingo)`

Answer (score 1):

Desde javascript(jquery) no se puede llamar el comando que tu quieres por que javascript se ejecuta del lado del cliente, para lo que tu quieres es necesario hacer una petición al servidor con ajax y desde de esa peticion ejecutar lo seguiente.

```
$comando = "php artisan C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoBINGO\revisionbingo";
$respuesta = shell_exec($comando);
echo $respuesta;
```

Comment: Bueno he creado la función y la he llamado directamente desde la ruta para probarlo, a priori no me da ningún error, llega hasta el final donde hace el echo (en mi caso he hecho un return "funcionó"), pero no me hace el insert que ejecuta esta comanda, lo compruebo desde mi mysql.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta rápida, es encapsular su ajax en una función Javascript, y copiar y pegar, cambiar la acción que se va a llamar en php y llamar la función javascript en onfish(). Si está haciendo programacion estructurada, se llenará de archivos 1 por cada función a ejecutar. ¿ Cómo está construido el Php?

Comment: No se si te he entendido pero yo NO necesito llamar a una función get (solo lo hago para recibir la fecha), lo que necesito es ejecutar una comanda php mediante consola CMD, he editado la pregunta al final he explicado/aclarado unas cosas

Comment: Gerardo Lozano le ha dado la respuesta, no se puede directamente con javascript, sino como lo describe él.